# Filter file content then read as csv in python

Tags: python, bash, pandas, csv

I use grep in bash script and then read as csv in pandas

Because my logfile is like below

`somegarbage
propercsv
somegarbage
propercsv`

I grep propercsv, generate a csv file and then load it using below code. I want to embedded this in python only.
That is filter out csv from a logfile given as argument

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f_input, open(sys.argv[2], 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    csv_output.writerow(cols)

    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|'):
        # Remove any entries that do not have a colon
        row = [c for c in row if c.find(':') != -1]
        # Convert remaining columns into a dictionary
        entries = {c.split(':')[0].strip() : c.split(':')[1].strip() for c in row}
        csv_output.writerow([entries.get(c, "") for c in cols])
```

Comment: Could you add some sample CSV lines to the question?

Comment: garbage \n |Name:abc|Place:Xyz|Time:123 \n gabage so i ` grep Name:` in a bash script and create a file.csv (i want to embed this in python only)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply filter lines of your log file that result in a suitable number of csv columns (e.g. >= 3) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import ifilter
import csv

data = []
cols = ['Name', 'Place', 'Time']

with open('logfile.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    for row in ifilter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3, csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|')):
        row = [c for c in row if c.find(':') != -1]
        entries = {c.split(':')[0].strip() : c.split(':')[1].strip() for c in row}
        data.append(entries.get(c, "") for c in cols)

print pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Giving you the following output:

```
  Name Place Time
0  abc   Xyz  123
1  abc   Xyz  123
2  abc   Xyz  123
3  abc   Xyz  123
```